# How to use a regexp to match dashes and ohter specific chars anywhere in thre string that contains numbers?

Tags: php, regex

I need to write a regexp that matches a string that has only numbers in it and these numbers can be divided by a comma or dash or underline or slash/backslash.

For example:

```
$reg = '/^\d+$/';

$phoneWithDashes = '343-1431-4412';
$phoneWithoutDashes = '34314314412'; 

echo preg_match($reg, $phoneWithDashes); // 0
echo preg_match($reg, $phoneWithoutDashes); // 1
```

How do I tell to this regexp '/^\d+$/' that I also want to match if there are dashes anywhere in the string?

Comment: Use `$phoneWithoutDashes = preg_replace('/[^d]/', '', $phoneWithDashes);`

Comment: Something like `if(ctype_digit(preg_replace('~[-,\\\/]+~', '', $string)){` should work... might want to check length of integer string as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since dashes can appear anywhere (between 2 digits), I would split on the dashes then check each string individually. Let's see how that translates to PHP code.

```php
function match_phone($phone) {
    $arr = preg_split('/[\/\\-_,]/', $phone);
    $reg = '/^\d+$/';
    foreach ($arr as $str) {
        if (!preg_match($reg, $str)) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

echo match_phone('343-1431-4412/7');    // 1
echo match_phone('343143144127');       // 1
echo match_phone('1234-illegal');       // 0
echo match_phone('11--22');             // 0
```